# How to send test Email from AMP for Email Playground?

Tags: email, amp-html, amp-email

I am trying to send test Email from AMP for Email Playground that is accessible [here.](https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/). However, I am not receiving any emails in my inbox. The documentation say I need to whitelist "amp@gmail.dev" email id. How do I do this? And also How do I send test emails from any of my own email id?

This is the AMP Email am sending. Is there any issue in the Email?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡️4email>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
</head>
<body>
  Hello, AMP4EMAIL to test.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMP Emails are only allowed from emails that are either whitelisted by Google or by yourself for the purpose of testing. It's done in your emails settings. `amp@gmail.dev` is the email from which `AMP for Email Playground` sends you the emails. You can whitelist this also from your email's settings.

---

**STEPS TO WHITELIST 'amp@gmail.dev':**

---

**1. Go to settings in the inbox which is on the top right side of your inbox.**
[image]

---

**2. Click on 'Developer Settings' link under the title Dynamic Email.**
[image]

---

**3. Enable the checkbox saying always allow email from amp@gmail.dev:**   [image]

---

**4. Trying clicking on send button with some amp email in the playground.**

---

**Steps to send email from custom email id for testing:**

> **Note:** Remember to send AMP email to any other email ID you need to get
>   your email whitelisted by Google.
>   https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/register The step below
>   is for sending email from an email that is not whitelisted by Google.

1. In the inbox settings, where you whitelisted `amp@gmail.dev`, add the email id you want to use for sending email in the input.
2. The email must be SPF, DKIM and DMARC-authenticated. You read what it is [here.](https://returnpath.com/downloads/authenticating-email-dmarc-spf-dkim-quick-start-guide/)
3. One of the easiest ways to send AMP Email is using AWS SES. Once AWS SES  is SPF, DKIM and DMARC-authenticated, you can use its SMTP interface to easily send email from any programing language with ease. Read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp.html) & [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dmarc.html).

Comment: Thank you for detailed instruction. I am following the same instruction, but for some reason, I do not see Developer settings for my Gmail account. I am using a free Gmail account, is that why?